# Relative clause in japanese

Tags: translation, relative-clauses

How do you form relative clauses that involves first person action? For example : "There aren't people I can talk to". Basically my doubt is about all those questions that require a particle like "to", "ni" and the like, when you can't use V-te ageru/kureru/morau to explicitate who's doing what to whom..Don't know if it's clear >.<

Comment: No, not really clear. But, "There aren't people I can talk to" could be translated as 話せる人々がいない. Maybe this already answers your question?

Comment: Are you talking about ambiguous cases like 彼女が好きな彼?

Comment: doesn't 話せる人々がいない mean "there aren't people who can talk" ?

Comment: Or maybe Japanese just uses an ambiguous sentence like that? I try to give an additional example: "the person I wrote a letter to", where basic sentence is 人に手紙を書いた. Do you simply drop that に ? (something like 私が手紙を書いた人 ?)

Comment: @Dandy Yes...it's ambiguous... "the person I wrote a letter to" can be「私が手紙を書いた人」。「話せる人が(誰も)いない。」「話す人が(誰も)いない。」「しゃべる人がいない。」etc. can be read as "I have no one I can talk to" and "There's no one who can talk". (「話す相手がいない。」「しゃべる相手がいない。」would be "I have no one to talk to".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might find the explanation of agency you are looking for in the introduction to the Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar (which I have not got to hand right now) but the other approach is to think of different ways of conveying what you want to say eg

"There aren't people I can talk to".

(which even in English feels like a rather clumsy construction anyway(?))

= There is nobody I can talk to/with
= There is nobody who can talk to/with me

= 僕と話せる人がいない

or perhaps even;

僕と話せる人は誰もいない